# Retorno do WebService não respeita o namespace do meu próprio WSDL

Tags: java, soap, namespace, wsdl

Olá!
Estou começando agora no mundo dos Webservices. Fiz um WS no wizard do eclipse utilizando axis 1 (se não me engano), no estilo "Bottom up":
No eclipse, posicionado na classe que será o WS: File->New->Other->Web Service
(Código da classe abaixo).

Ocorre que "Cliente" e "Endereco" estão no pacote "modelo". Na geração do WSDL o axis especifica estes objetos no namespace modelo (mod:), porém o RETORNO do web service especifica o namespace principal no retorno (), nas NÃO especifica o namespace http://modelo.costa.regis para os campos de Cliente e Endereço.

O que está faltando aqui? Alguma anotação na classe? Como eu faço pro retorno da classe, que é na verdade o próprio objeto, seja enviada no namespace correto?

Obrigado por qualquer dica gente. Estou meio desesperado aqui.

CÓDIGO DA CLASSE:
package regis.costa;

import regis.costa.modelo.Cliente;
import regis.costa.modelo.Endereco;

public class CadCliente {
    public Cliente alteraCliente(Cliente clienteAtual) {
        Cliente clienteNovo = new Cliente();

```
    clienteNovo.setCodigo(clienteAtual.getCodigo());
    clienteNovo.setNome("Olá " + clienteAtual.getNome().toUpperCase());

    Endereco[] anterior = clienteAtual.getEnderecos();
    int quant = anterior.length;
    quant++;
    Endereco[] enderecos = new Endereco[quant];

    for (int i = 0; i < anterior.length; i++) {
        enderecos[i] = anterior[i];
    }

    enderecos[--quant] = new Endereco();
    enderecos[quant].setBairro("novo bairro");
    enderecos[quant].setNumero(111);
    enderecos[quant].setRua("nova rua");

    clienteNovo.setEnderecos(enderecos);

    return clienteNovo;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. Peguei o WSDL gerado pelo método Bottom Up, e gerei um NOVO Servidor Webserver pelo método Top Down.

O inexplicável Axis gerou os programas do novo Webservice (Interface, SoapBindingImpl, Service, ServiceLocator, SoapBindingStub e SoapBindingSkeleton). Não sei por que gerou todos esses programas, o que ocorre é que esse novo WS gerado respeita totalmente o WSDL. A partir daí eu passei a fazer qualquer alteração que preciso no Webservice via WSDL e regerando o servidor.